# Visual Studio 2019 - SSDT

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools, visual-studio-2019

I have recently installed Visual Studio 2019 and installed the "Data Storage and processing" Workload to give me access to SSDT so I can create Reporting Services Projects.  When clicking File > New > Project I don't get the ability to either create SSRS/SSIS/SSAS projects?  I was under the impression that these would now automatically be installed when selecting "Data Storage and processing" during the Install.  How can I get these project templates installed?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the documentation [Changes in SSDT for Visual Studio 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017#changes-in-ssdt-for-visual-studio-2019):

> - For SQL Database Projects, install the Data storage and Processing workload for Visual Studio *(What you have installed)*
> - For Analysis Services, Integration Services or Reporting Services projects, install the appropriate extension(s) from the marketplace *(What you need to install)*

Go to the Manage Extensions, and Online -> Visual Studio Marketplace and search for "reporting Services":

[image]

You'll find the other extensions under similar names (note SSIS is currently in Preview).